# Why isn't Groovy (Jenkins pipeline) not recognizing class (static) variables?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm following an example in [Getting To Know Groovy Variables And Their Functions](https://marketsplash.com/tutorials/groovy/groovy-variables/) and have the following. `EnvironmentMgr` is a singleton class I've defined somewhere else, and it works.

```
@Singleton
class EnvironmentMgr {
  String ecsCluster = "sandbox"
  ...
}

abstract class EcsService {
  def setup() {
    if (envMgr == null) {
      println "envMgr is null"
      envMgr = EnvironmentMgr.instance
    }
  }

  protected static def envMgr = null
}

class Service1 extends EcsService {
  def setup() {
    super.setup()
    // Do something for Service1
  }
}

class Service2 extends EcsService {
  def setup() {
    super.setup()
    // Do something for Service2
  }
}

def svc1 = new Service1()
svc1.setup()
def svc2 = new Service2()
svc2.setup()
```

I expect the `println` statement in `EcsService:setup()` to be printed once, but it's printed both calls. Why is that? How can I make it work? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
The above code works as expected as straight Groovy code on my Mac, but when run in a Jenkins pipeline, the static-ness isn't recognized.

Comment: Can we see how your `EnvironmentMgr` class is defined? Would help to isolate the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Can you try adding `static def envMgr = null` above the `setup()` function in `EcsService` and see if that makes a difference? I *think* that will make the `envMgr` variable shared across all instances of the class, but don't have a local setup available to test it.

Comment: @AaronMeese, yes that works, and I'll use it as a workaround. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Although I don't understand why my original code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue is due to the `envMgr` property is not behaving as a static property in the Jenkins environment. To ensure that the `envMgr` property is a shared/static property across all instances of `EcsService` in a Jenkins pipeline, you can explicitly declare it as a static property using the static keyword:

```
abstract class EcsService {
  static def envMgr = null  // Declare envMgr as a static property

  def setup() {
    if (envMgr == null) {
      println "envMgr is null"
      envMgr = EnvironmentMgr.instance
    }
  }
}
```